# Value null at 'stateMachineArn' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null

Tags: javascript, aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions

I followed [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/create-a-serverless-workflow-step-functions-lambda/) and added the AWS Step Functions.

But when I used the code below to try to call the Step Functions,

```
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax';

// ...
ajax.post(
  url,
  {
    input: JSON.stringify({
      formId: action.payload.formId,
      fields: action.payload.fields,
    }),
  },
  { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
).pipe(
  map(res => actions.sendRequestSucceed(res)),
  catchError(actions.sendRequestFailed),
)
```

It returns the error:

```
response: {
    message: "1 validation error detected: Value null at 'stateMachineArn' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null"
    __type: "com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took me a while to figure out.

First need set up API Gateway, you can follow [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-api-gateway.html).

[image]

Note the **Action** is `StartExecution`.

Here is `StartExecution` [API document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StartExecution.html).

```
{
   "input": "string",
   "name": "string", (Optional)
   "stateMachineArn": "string"
}
```

After adding `stateMachineArn` which can be found at in your Step Functions -> State machines

[image]

in the code

```
ajax.post(
  url,
  {
    input: JSON.stringify({
      formId: action.payload.formId,
      fields: action.payload.fields,
    }),
    stateMachineArn: 'arn:aws:states:us-west-2:000000000000:stateMachine:SendFormStateMachine',
  },
  // ...
```

Then it works.

Also note StartExecution `input` only accept string. If you need pass an object, you can use `JSON.stringify`.